# Get Unicode character from onKeyDown event in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, keycode

I want to get Unicode character when I input into soft keyboard (I use key down event).

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //I tried this but not work
        Log.d(TAG,event.getCharacters());          

    }
```

For example, when I input something like: '~', '@' , 'a', 'ă', '©' How can I get these characters if I have keycode?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [the KeyEvent docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) and do a search for "@" on the page.  They all appear to be on there.  Also see the [getUnicodeChar()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getUnicodeChar%28%29) method.